# Converting .txt to .csv using Pandas not working

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am starting to learn about Pandas.

I am trying to export some data from a .txt file to .csv

I have tried everything that I found on the web (which is usually always the same method)

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv (r'file name.txt') #in my pc i have the actual path and file name
read_file.to_csv (r'file name.csv', index=None)
```

This code throws the following error:

```
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

My .txt file looks like this

[image: Image of CSV text file]

I would be very glad if anyone can help me! Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the actual question? CSV is a text file format. The extension doesn't matter. The error means there's no data in that text file to read

Comment: Post the example as text in the question. Images can't be copied, tested or googled. What you show is **already a CSV** assuming the lines are wrapped by your editor. There may be blank lines that have to be skipped, but we can't guess from that image

Comment: Does your filename contain spaces? It looks like that. Can you replace spaces with underscores in filename and try again?

Comment: @Sergiu all file systems can handle spaces. If the file couldn't be found, the error wouldn't complain about an empty file

Comment: Does the file actually contain data? Are you looking at the correct file?

Comment: It's resolved now. I opened the txt file before on the code and did not close it before trying to read the file. I just had to close it before reading. Thanks for the comments!